# In GatsbyJS, when passing props to a linked page, how do I set a defaultProp?

Tags: javascript

I'm experiencing a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'serviceCategory' of null` issue when the "linked page" refreshes (f5) or when the page is visited as direct traffic.

I've tried setting defaultProps, but it's not triggering.

Here is my current setup:

```
<Link
  to="/locations"
  state={{
    serviceCategory: "FILTER",
  }}
>
```

linked page

```
const Locations = ({ location }) => {

  const { state = {} } = location
  const { serviceCategory } = state

  const [category, setCategory] = useState(() => {
    return location.state === null ? "ALL" : serviceCategory
  })
}

...

Locations.defaultProps = {
  location: {
    state: {
      serviceCategory: "ALL",
    },
  },
}

export default Locations
```

`defaultProps` is no where to be found in Gatsby's documentation, so i'm thinking of a different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `defaultProps` won't work in this case because gatsby uses `@reach/router` internally and `props.location` value is overriden by that.

You can either use a different variable name inside `defaultProps` or use a default value for state.

```
const state = location.state || { serviceCategory: 'ALL' }
```

Notice that

```
 const { state = {serviceCategory:'ALL'} } = location
```

won't work because default initializer in destructuring only works for `undefined` values and  not `null` values. And your value is null in this case.